# Call CellForRow after completion block

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function that goes off to the web and downloads data which is then put into a TableViewCell.

My problem is that the CellForRow delegate method is being called before the app has got data back from the web.

So how can I call the CellForRow delegate method after I've got the data back from the web?

Comment: did u try table reloadData method to refresh table

Comment: You have to reload your table's data in the async block after retrieving the data. I recommend posting your code if you still have issues.

Comment: you either make the request sooner, or you call `reloadTableView` in the completion block for the request

Comment: I don't know how things work with swift, but I can give you a hint. You just need to reloadTable after receiving data. That is all!

Answer (score 1):

Does your function have a proper completion block? It sounds like what's happening is that you're calling `cellForRow` synchronously, whereas the process being sent off for download is asynchronous. I suspect your code looks something like this:

```
// ...
[self downloadMethod];
[self cellDelegateCall];
// ...
```

The system doesn't know how long `downloadMethod` is going to take, so it'll just execute `cellDelegateCall` right away. What you'd need is a proper completion block:

```
// ...
[self downloadMethodWithCompletion:^(BOOL successful) {
    if (successful) {
        [self cellDelegateCall];
    }
}];
// ...
```

Getting familiar with writing your own blocks can be confusing at first. [This website](http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com/) is a great resource. Even after a few years of writing blocks, I still find myself checking it out from time to time. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

No need to explicitly call cellForRow delegate , You just reload your table view after receiving your data it will call `cellForRow` delegate.

**Swift 2.3:**

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    self.tableView.reloadData()
     })
```

**Swift 3:**

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to get used to about `cellForRow` is that you most often don't call it directly.  Just know that it's going to get triggered at various times, like when the table is first drawn in the view controller and when a new cell is needed for the table.  And as the others have said, if you do need to trigger `cellForRow`, call `tableView.reloadData()`.

Answer (score 0):

Once the data is downloaded from web, you need to call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` on tableView.